# Convert .NET UTC Time in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format a JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date)

I have an HTML page that uses JQuery. My JQuery hits a .NET Web Service that does the following:

```
return DateTime.UtcNow;
```

An example value returned looks like the following:

```
"/Date(-62135578800000)/"
```

In my JavaScript, I'm try to parse the date as follows:

```
var lastOrderDate = GetValueFromService();
var d = new Date(parseInt(lastOrderDate));
alert(d);
```

When the alert statement is hit, I see "Invalid Date" in the alert window. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That post doesn't seem to address my issue. Can't figure out what's different.

Comment: @JQueryMobile the answer calls `substr(6)` to remove the `/Date(` portion, should solve your problem.

Comment: That seems strange because you get negative value. Maybe there is overflow?

Comment: You probably is sending the DateTime default value (01/01/0001) to the javascript.